# Spring does not load data beans (@Repository) from dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-data, spring-boot-configuration

#### Situation

I have a modular Spring Boot application, which currently consists of the `applicationProject`, that includes the first sub module `moduleA` as dependencies (maven).

This allows the `applicationProject` to be a single java class, which initializes the Spring application, where as the actual functionality is delivered by the modules defined as dependencies.

All my modules and also the `applicationProject` are underneath the base package `com.mycompany.myproduct`.

My `applicationProject` java class looks as simple as this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ="com.mycompany.myproduct")
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

In my `moduleA` project I do not use any `@ComponentScan` annotation or extension of it.

#### Issue

When I start my application this way I get a **`UnsatisfiedDependencyException`**, while Spring tries to initialize a bean `ServiceA` that it self depends on another bean `RepositoryA` both defined in `moduleA`.

This makes me assume that Spring does detect the beans, but does not build the dependency tree correctly resulting in a bad bean instantiation order.

When adding

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.myproduct")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.myproduct")
```

to the initializing `MyApp` class, the spring loads the beans correctly and the application runs successfully.

To me this seems like a workaround or why would I need to declare the base package again for `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` when I already declare the base package in the `SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Or is this even a flaw due the independent spring projects?

Comment: how does your Repository class look like . DO you have `@Repository` annotation

Comment: Yes, my repository class is configured the correct way with the `@Repository` annotation and also works perfectly on test inside `moduleA`.